# html5 input type number with regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, html, pattern-matching

I'm trying to get regex pattern in input type number to show only numbers and forward slash. I tried something like this.

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9\/]*">
```

But getting only 0-9 number pad. How can I show 0-9 number pad as well as forward slash `"/"` in regex.

Comment: it is not semantically correct to use an input with a number type and requesting a non-number value.

Comment: then do u have anything with javascript?

Comment: I did not understand you were looking for to select a mobile virtual keyboard

Answer (score 2):

You could use input type "text" for only the validation purpose.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9\/]*" >
```

You can consider the "tel" input type, for a simpler keybord layout containing the slash on a mobile device

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9\/]*">
```

Comment: It gives some symbols also..How can I restrict those and allow only forward slash?

Comment: In my opinion that is not possible, your phone has some default keyboards you can chose from through the html5 tag, thats it. I think if you want a more specific phonelayout thats only possible with a native app. (If it is possible)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the input type to `text`:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9\/]*" name="text_with_numbers">
```

See [more information here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/).

Comment: It does not matter if you give text or not, it won't users submit junk, only what is allowed.